# The Difference between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am a beginner to iPhone development, I know the only very basic concepts of it. While I'm reading, I got a small question, what is the main difference between cocoa and cocoa touch?

Can anyone one please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cocoa versus Cocoa Touch - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297841/cocoa-versus-cocoa-touch-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cocoa is for Mac OS X, Cocoa Touch for iOS. In Cocoa Touch, the UI classes all start with the prefix "UI" as in "UIButton", "UIView", etc. pp. while in Cocoa, the have the "NS" prefix as in "NSButton", "NSButton" (the NS stands for NextStep which is a predecessor to Mac OS X).

Cocoa has more features than Cocoa Touch. But overall their APIs are very similar (they are not the same, but you will likely find it easy to find your way in one API if you already know the other).

Answer (score 3):

As told very well by DarkDust would like to add few more points.

The main difference between Cocoa and Cocoa touch is that the ***UI classes*** and ***APIs*** aren't the same as Mac OS X, so instead of **NSTextField**, you have **UITextField**.

Cocoa is the application framework for **Mac OS X**.

Cocoa Touch is the application framework for **iPhone** and **iPod Touch** - very similar to Cocoa.

Cocoa is commonly referred to as the combination of the Foundation and **AppKit** frameworks.
Cocoa Touch is the combination of the Foundation and **UIKit** frameworks

There are also some differences between the Foundation frameworks in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, most commonly missing classes, eg, Cocoa has **NSHost** and Cocoa Touch does not.