# What are objective c runtime features?

Tags: swift, objective-c, runtime, terminology, nsobject

In a blog post I have just read:

'Swift allows us to extend classes from NSObject to get Objective-C runtime features for an object. It also allows us to annotate Swift methods with @objc to allow the methods to be used by the Objective-C runtime.'

I don't understand the term objective-C runtime features. Is it meaning that the code could be used in a objective-C project as well?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/objective_c_runtime, http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/objective_c_runtime)

> The Objective-C runtime is a runtime library that provides support for the dynamic properties of the Objective-C language, and as such is linked to by all Objective-C apps. Objective-C runtime library support functions are implemented in the shared library found at /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib.

That API is useful primarily for developing bridge layers between Objective-C and other languages, or for low-level debugging. You most likely don't need to use it.

Even when written without a single line of Objective-C code, every Swift app executes inside the Objective-C runtime, so that's why you can access it.

You can do things like [swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C Runtime**

A lot of programming languages is ship with a kind of `runtime/standard library` which includes some core/base functionality

`Objective-C Runtime` is responsible for **dynamism**, memory management(allocation, reference counting...) and other language features. It is a layer between compiler and `core libraries/frameworks`.

Objective-C is `dynamic` language because shift focus from `compile time` to `runtime`:

- Dynamic typing - figure out object's class in runtime. inheritance and other OOP principles
- Dynamic binding - figure out invoked method in runtime. `Message dispatch mechanism`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218731/4770877)
- Dynamic loading - you are able to lazy-loading a new module in runtime.

Other features:

- basic structures like class, object, variable, property, method
- functions for working with these structures

  - Introspection - get/read info about class/object in runtime. For example instance variables, methods names, method arguments. class_getName
  - Reflection - modify its own structure and behavior. For example allocate new class, add variable, add method. class_addMethod
  - objc_msgSend - based on message dispatch
  - Swizzling - swap method realisation in runtime. method_exchangeImplementations. [[Objective C],](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412849/4770877) [[Swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412970/4770877) swizzling example

Using [[`@objc vs dynamic`]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60937714/4770877) expose Swift's API for Objective-C and adds a dynamic behaviour for Swift code. It is useful when you need something which is not possible to do with usual swift approaches. Good examples are KVO, swizzling...

[[KVO]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179947/4770877)

**Objective-C vs Swift**

`Swift` can use `Objective-C Runtime` library.

Swift has better performance(based on table dispatch) but Objective-C is more dynamic language